# Laravel order by not working on related columns on datatable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Basically, my backend is:

```
$columns = array(
    0 => 'purchased_date',
    1 => 'supplier',
    2 => 'purchased_code',
    3 => 'grand_total',
    4 => 'paid_amount',
    5 => 'overall_due_amount',
    6 => 'payment_status',
    7 => 'action',
);
$limit = $request->input('length');
$start = $request->input('start');
$order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
$dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');


$query = Purchase::with(['supplier:id,name','purchasePayments']);
$purchased_date = $request->columns[0]['search']['value'];
if (!empty($purchased_date)) {
    $query->where('purchased_date', 'like', '%' . $purchased_date . '%');
}
$supplier_search = $request->columns[1]['search']['value'];
if (!empty($supplier_search)) {
    $query->whereHas('supplier', function($q) use($supplier_search){
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $supplier_search . '%');
    });
}
$purchased_code = $request->columns[2]['search']['value'];
if (!empty($purchased_code)) {
    $query->where('purchased_code', 'like', '%' . $purchased_code . '%');
}
$totalData = $query->count();


//HERE HOW COULD I ORDER USING SUPPLIER NAME
//suppliers is the name of the table
//and supplier is the relation defined inside purchase model

$order = 'suppliers.name';


$query->orderBy($order, $dir);
if ($limit != '-1') {
    $query->offset($start)->limit($limit);
}
$records = $query->get();

$totalFiltered = $totalData;
$data = array();
if (isset($records)) {
    foreach ($records as $k => $v) {
        $nestedData['id'] = $v->id;
        $nestedData['purchased_date'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $v->purchased_date)->format('Y-m-d');
        $nestedData['supplier'] = $v->supplier->name;
        $nestedData['purchased_code'] = $v->purchased_code;
        $nestedData['grand_total'] = $v->grand_total;
        $nestedData['paid_amount'] = $v->purchasePayments->sum('paid_amount');
        $nestedData['overall_due_amount'] = $v->overall_due_amount;
        $nestedData['payment_status'] = PaymentHelper::getPaymentStatusBadge($v->purchasePayments->last()->payment_status);
        $nestedData['action'] = \View::make('admin.purchases.action')->with('r', $v)->render();
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
}
```

Here, how could I order the full results based on the supplier name. Here, `suppliers` is the name of the table and `supplier` is the name of the relation defined on the purchase model. Is there any way to deal with this situation where I need to order based on the related model

Answer (score 0):

It's because eager loading isn't building your query as you anticipate.

```php
// Instead of: 

$query->orderBy($order, $dir); ❌

// Use this:

$query->join('suppliers', 'purchases.id', '=', 'suppliers.purchase_id')
        ->orderBy('suppliers.name', $dir) ✅
```

To avoid ambiguous column names. i.e: `id` (Between `purchases` and `suppliers` tables.), modify:

```php
// Instead of:

$records = $query->get(); ❌

// Use this:

$records = $query->get(["purchases.*"]); ✅
```

**NOTE:** Eager loading still works with the above implementation.

Comment: with join it is giving duplicate records for one-many relation how could I deal with that?

Comment: @AayushDahal, Are duplicate records happening on _purchases_ or _suppliers_?. [->distinct()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause) may come in handy here.